# Ubuntu On Aakash

Tags: android, tablet

I have an [Aakash 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aakash_%28tablet%29) (Ubislate 7Ci) tablet. It runs on Android 4.0 ICS. I want to make it run on Ubuntu. Give me the procedures involved.

Comment: I did not ask for the list of hardwares supported by Ubuntu Touch. I wanted to know the procedure to make Aakash 2 run on Ubuntu.

Comment: That falls under the "Ubuntu Touch" category.  The list of supported hardware is on the link you specified, and if your tablet is not listed it is likely not supported.  Therefore the link given is correct, as "I want to make it run on Ubuntu" is also synonymous to "Is my device compatible" which is what is answered at the "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for flashing a phone/tablet and installing Ubuntu Touch is available in this webpage https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Flashing_the_device